# How to prevent a mobile app from being debugged - React Native?

Tags: android, ios, swift, react-native, security

How to prevent a debugger from attaching to the running application in a react native app?

Comment: There are a lot of known anti-debugging techniques, but I don't think many of them can be applied in React Native, usually such measures are implemented in C. Implementing good anti-debugging measures require a lot of knowledge on processes, threads, debugging and the underlaying platform. Alternatively there are commercial tools for hardening apps, not sure how much of them do work with React Native. On such solutions as a rule of thumb you get what you pay for, which means the more expensive the solution the better the protection.

Answer (score 0):

with XCode just running in Release mode, in Android Studio I only build apk file to test, before build .aab file to upload to Google Console